# How do I access an NSMutableArray Created in Class A in Class B

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, linker-errors

I have a NSMutableArray declared in one class, named `ArraySetup`, and I need to populate it from a file in the `AppDelegate`'s `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. In my ArraySetup.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ArraySetup : NSObject
{
    NSMutableArray *places;
}


extern NSMutableArray *places;

@end
```

(.m has only default code)
And in my AppDelegate.m:

```
// The ArraySetup.h has been imported
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
 NSArray *pathList = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);


    NSString *placesPath = [[pathList objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"places.plist"];


    NSArray *placesPLIST = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:placesPath];

    if (placesPLIST) {
        places = [placesPLIST mutableCopy];
    } else {
    places = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
}
```

The code gives me no errors, but when I run my program on the simulator, I get the error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_places", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I think we need to take a step back here.
What you're trying to is to assign a value to a variable called `places` of type `NSMutableArray` to a class called `ArraySetup`.

First of all you need to create an instance of `ArraySetup`:

`ArraySetup *arraySetup = [[ArraySetup alloc] init];`

The second problem here is that `NSMutableArray *places;` in `ArraySetup` is an instance variable and not accessible outside of `ArraySetup`. To expose it to other classes you can create a property like so:

`@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *places`

and then you can set its value in `AppDelegate` like so:

`arraySetup.places = [placesPLIST mutableCopy];`

I suggest you read more about [constructors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_%28object-oriented_programming%29) and [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29) in object oriented programming.

Good luck.

Comment: I'm using this for something to populate a tableview, so it will go to a view controller. can I just use `ArraySetup.places`? Without creating the instance

Comment: Also, I'm kind of weary using instances because since I need to update tableviews and other things with this array, if I use an instance, the tableview will only have a value in the instance, right?